# If/else statement making link work or disabled

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Info about the table in question:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen th</td>
<td align="left">2 vær.</td>
<td align="left">66m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Udlejet</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen mf</td>
<td align="left">2 vær.</td>
<td align="left">47m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Udlejet</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen tv</td>
<td align="left">3 vær.</td>
<td align="left">81m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Ledig</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm currently giving a table row a class depending on the text input in a td with the class 'status'. The text is written by the author in WordPress. The classes are used for some custom CSS and hopefully making it easier to disable the link for one of them

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('.table-2 tr').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).find('.status').text();
});
});
```

In the code below I'm making the table row with the class table-link work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(".table-link").click(function() {
       window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

My problem is I've two different status:

status 1: working link called 'Ledig'.
status 2: disabled link called 'Udlejet'.

Can I make a if else statement where only status 1 is going to be a working link?

Comment: How do you know something is status 1 vs status 2?

Comment: I have a table with 4 tds, where the last one has a class called 'status'. In this cell there is either written status1 or status2 - which is where the first script adds this to the tablerow as a class

Comment: Alright, so `if(theTrTheTableLinkIsInHasTheClassOfStatus2){ ...do not do the link... }` ?

Comment: Yeah something like that. But I was wondering if it was possible/better to just make the second script happen for status1 (the working one) and not for status2 (the disabled one)?

Comment: If your first script runs before the second one, sure, you could do a delegate event listener on the `.table-2 tr.status1`

Comment: It does :) I read something about on() and .hasClass(), but Im unsure how to use that with the second script

Comment: Take a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some sort of if statement maybe something like:

```
if($('.table-2 tr .status').val() =='Ledig'){
    $(".table-link").bind("click", function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
}
```

although you might need to do this in such a way as it loops through each table row.

### Edit

This works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".table-2 tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".status").html() == 'Ledig'){
      $(this).bind("click", function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-2">
<tbody>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen th</td>
<td align="left">2 vær.</td>
<td align="left">66m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Udlejet</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen mf</td>
<td align="left">2 vær.</td>
<td align="left">47m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Udlejet</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-link" data-href="http://jantzenproperties.dk/for-lejere/">
<td style="text-align: center;" align="left">Stuen tv</td>
<td align="left">3 vær.</td>
<td align="left">81m2</td>
<td class="status" align="right">Ledig</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```